# OnPageSelected Snapping causes layout delay

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I will try to explain my problem as good as I can.

I've got a viewpager which contains a lot of pages on which I can swipe horisontally between. I've added a listener (OnPageChangeListener) cause I need to do some stuffs when pages changes.

In OnPageSelected I update a header, which is just a TextView. Thing is, this updating causes my slider to "lag" for a millisecond, which interrupts the smooth flow. But this only occurs if I do a "fast" swipe, meaning the actual snapping will cause the slider to change page. If I slide the entire way to the next page, it is fine.

Basically I'm wondering what my options are here. I would like to update the header when the snapping to the page has been completely done, not at the same time causing the small flicker effect.

Comment: have you gotten the solution??

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) viewpager **onPageSelected** will be invoked when a new page becomes selected. **Animation is not necessarily complete**. If you change header in onPageSelected then change in UI causes delay in animation and it will look like a lag.

The solution for it that you can change the header in **onPageScrollStateChanged (int state)** method.

```
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
             case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
               int arg0=pager.getCurrentItem();
               if(arg0==0)
            {

                header.setText("Your Text Here");
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Problem with this solution is that the takes some time for the viewpager to achieve it's IDLE state. This also means that if the user constantly swipes, it never updates.